# Differences in runtime over dataframe versus matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, apply

```
cos.sim <- function(X, ix) 
{
  A = X[ix[1],]
  B = X[ix[2],]
  return( sum(A*B)/sqrt(sum(A^2)*sum(B^2)) )
}   


library(pbapply)
X = matrix(runif(512*100), ncol=512)
Y = data.frame(X)


res = pbsapply(1:100, function(x) cos.sim(X, c(1,x)) )
res = pbsapply(1:100, function(x) cos.sim(Y, c(1,x)) )
```

When calculating the result, The first line takes 0 sec, but the second line takes 10 times longer. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you get a numerical value for the difference with `Sys.time`? This is most likely due to `pbsapply`, and the way you index in the function.

Comment: @mhh thanks, we can easily switch off pbsapply by sapply, but the results are the same

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-July/282666.html